# PHP image uploading is not working

Tags: php, image, image-uploading

I have the below code which is not uploading the image tried many thing but does not work. I can not figure it out what is the issue but log ago the same code was used to work.

**HTML Form**

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
<input size="25" name="file" type="file" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10pt" class="box"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

**The last try code is below:**

```
$change="";
$abc="";


define ("MAX_SIZE","12000");
function getExtension($str) {
        $i = strrpos($str,".");
        if (!$i) { return ""; }
        $l = strlen($str) - $i;
        $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
        return $ext;
}

$errors=0;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


if ($image) {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {
            $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> ';
            $errors=1;
}else{
$size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024){
    $change='<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div> ';
    $errors=1;
}


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" ){
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}else if($extension=="png"){
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

}else {
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

echo $scr;

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

$newwidth=1990;
$newheight=1100;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

$imu    =   mysql_query("select max(id)+1 as id from menu_items");
$ints   =   mysql_fetch_array($imu);
$chk    =   $ints['id'];

$ids    =   $ints['id'];

$srids  =   $ints['showroom_id'];

$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$ext = end((explode(".", $name))); # extra () to prevent notice

$ses_msr    =   $_SESSION['ses_member_id'];
$folderPath = "images/rest_menu_items";
mkdir($folderPath);

$filename = "images/rest_menu_items/".$ids.'.'.$ext;
$filename1 = "images/small". $_FILES['file']['name'];

imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);
mysql_query("
UPDATE menu_items
SET
    filename='".$ids.'.'.$ext."'
WHERE
    id='".$_GET['id']."'
");

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
}}

}
```

Comment: Please provide form example and any logs/errors/debug info

Comment: `functiongetExtension` space missing? Right on is `function getExtension` ?

Comment: @Ostin please check i have updated my question

Comment: @Evus i cant really find this function i tried would you please help?

Comment: 6th row `functiongetExtension($str){` See @PravinVavadiya answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix these:

Row 6:

```
function getExtension($str){
```

Row 48:

```
echo $src;
```

Row 79:

```
mkdir($folderPath);
```

And make sure you have write permissions.

Also PHP error log would help a lot. You can debug your code if you put

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

to beginning of file.

Also make sure that you have installed [PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php).

Create file whre only content is.

```
<?php
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
?>
```

There should be "**GD Supported Enabled**" If it is not found you need to install [it](http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php).

If it is present then check [write permissions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php), file test.txt must be present. So create empty file test.txt to test this.

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
if (is_writable($filename)) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}
```

If these things is checked then following code will work.

Tested code that work. I removed queries and SESSION data because I cant debug them without having all code.

```
<?php
$change="";
$abc="";


define ("MAX_SIZE","12000");
function getExtension($str) {
        $i = strrpos($str,".");
        if (!$i) { return ""; }
        $l = strlen($str) - $i;
        $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
        return $ext;
}

$errors=0;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


if ($image) {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {
            $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> ';
            $errors=1;
}else{
$size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024){
    $change='<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div> ';
    $errors=1;
}


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" ){
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}else if($extension=="png"){
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

}else {
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

echo $src;

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

$newwidth=1990;
$newheight=1100;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

imagejpeg($tmp,"Test.jpg",100);


imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
}}

}
?>
```

Comment: please check my code in the quesiton i have updated & no error is there after error_reporting( E_ALL );

Comment: Row 48 `$scr` to `$src`. Come back with errors so this community can help you. It's impossible to help without them. Eg we don't know if you problem is write permission or mysql queries or something else.

Comment: Added tested code. If that code is not working your problem is mysql queries, write permissions or you have not installed GD as I stated.

Comment: where it is saving i cant see the image where it is?

Comment: Same folder where your PHP file is. Named Test.jpg. I'm correcting my last comment. If this is not working your problem is write permission or GD. If this works your problem was MySQL or Session data

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini added info how to check if GD is installed and enabled. Check that first. If it is present then you need to check file permissions.

Comment: this file is writeable.

Comment: If these all check out and still it is not working, then I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `Function` syntax. add space after `function` keyword

```
function getExtension($str){
 $i=strrpos($str,".");
 if(!$i){return"";}
 $l=strlen($str)-$i;
 $ext=substr($str,$i+1,$l);
 return$ext;
}
```

For getting Error use below code.

```
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
```

Comment: Well i did this but nothing happened no error nothing and its not uploading

Comment: Fix other syntax error. Eg line 48. `echo$scr;` to `echo $scr;`.